# How to swap dataTable row values?

Tags: c#

MyScenario,I have three rows .I want swap values of first column.How to achieve this?

Comment: is the content of the DataTable dynamic or static?

Answer (score 2):

```
function SwapField(DataTable table, string columnName, int firstRowIndex, int secondRowIndex)
{
  int columnIndex = table.Columns.GetOrdinal(columnName);
  if (columnIndex == -1)
  {
    // Throw exception
  }

  var secondRowField = dataTable.Rows[secondRowIndex][columnIndex];
  dataTable.Rows[secondRowIndex][columnIndex] = dataTable.Rows[firstRowIndex][columnIndex];
  dataTable.Rows[firstRowIndex][columnIndex] = secondRowField;
}
```

And then
SwapField(dataTable, 'Column', 0, 1) to swap the first 2 rows field values

Answer (score 0):

I don't really see the problem unless you want some generic algorithm that works across any number of rows; in any case you need to define between which rows exactly you want to swap values; swapping between two rows is really straight-forward, especially if you work with version 4 of the Framework, in which you have two neat extension methods for DataRow: Field and SetField. If not, you'll need to get the ItemArrays of each DataRow, swap the values in the arrays and assign the arrays back to their rows.

Answer (score 0):

Sample code to swap the two rows of a DataGridView

```
   private void lblMoveDown_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       moveDown();
    }

    private void lblMoveUp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       moveUp();
    }

    private void moveUp()
    {
        if (dgvTemplateListToManage.RowCount > 0)
        {
            if (dgvTemplateListToManage.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
            {                  
                DataTable dt=dgvTemplateListToManage.DataSource as DataTable;
                int rowIndex = dgvTemplateListToManage.SelectedRows[0].Index;

                if (rowIndex != 0)
                {
                    DataRow row = dt.Rows[rowIndex];
                    DataRow drToDown= dt.Rows[rowIndex-1];
                    DataTable dtTemp = dt.Copy();

                    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
                    {
                        if (i != 0)
                        {
                            dtTemp.Rows[rowIndex][i] = drToDown[i].ToString();
                        }
                    }
                    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
                    {
                        if (i != 0)
                        {
                            dtTemp.Rows[rowIndex-1][i] = row[i].ToString();
                        }
                    }
                    dgvTemplateListToManage.DataSource = dtTemp;
                }

            }
        }
    }

    private void moveDown()
    {           
        DataTable dt = dgvTemplateListToManage.DataSource as DataTable;
        int rowIndex = dgvTemplateListToManage.SelectedRows[0].Index;
        int lastRowIndex = dgvTemplateListToManage.Rows.Count - 1;

        if (lastRowIndex != rowIndex)
        {

            DataRow row = dt.Rows[rowIndex];
            DataRow drToUp = dt.Rows[rowIndex + 1];
            DataTable dtTemp = dt.Copy();

            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                if (i != 0)
                {
                    dtTemp.Rows[rowIndex][i] = drToUp[i].ToString();
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                if (i != 0)
                {
                    dtTemp.Rows[rowIndex + 1][i] = row[i].ToString();
                }
            }
            dgvTemplateListToManage.DataSource = dtTemp;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -3):

you need to write some thing like

```
`DataRow row = dt.Rows[index];
 dt.RemoveAt(index);
 dt.InsertAt(index -1);`
```